# ERROR:socket_posix.cc(93)] CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol (97)

Tags: cypress

I am getting the error below on Gitlab, but while trying to run the test on local its workig fine. Can anyone help here?

ERROR:socket_posix.cc(93)] CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol (97)

I am trying to run test spec in cypress, on localhost its working fine but while I push to Gitlab its giving the error above.

Comment: I have the same issue, but it just works for me fine. Don't know the cause though..